# Reducer exception

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm just starting on my redux studied and already at the first try i cant find a solution to this exception.

**The problem appears when i try to render my App wrapped in the Provider.**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware()}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image]

Comment: https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store#the-solution-configurestore

Comment: Also, please follow the official tutorials at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index - redux has changed a lot in the past few years and from the looks of it you are following a very outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers)` accepts up to 3 arguments. The first argument, `rootReducer` is a required argument. You are missing a reducer.